# Is there a way to see just what was sent in a Google Docs collaboration invitation e-mail?

Tags: email, google-docs

Suppose someone does the following in Google Docs:

1. Create a Google Doc (or other type of document) with some content.
2. Click the Share button to share it with another person.
3. Click Advanced in the lower right corner of the popup for additional options.
4. In the Invite People box, type in an e-mail address.
5. Below that, ensure that the "Notify people" checkbox is checked, and click "Add message."
6. A new text box appears, in which you can compose a message.  It is a relatively small, non-resizeable box.
7. Beneath that message entry box, check the checkbox "Send a copy to myself."
8. Click the blue "Send" button to the left.

In the e-mail the document author receives, there is a copy of the message but a note below it saying:

> This is a courtesy copy of an email for your record only. It's not the same email your collaborators received. Click [here](https://support.google.com/drive/?p=courtesy_copy) to learn more.

However, the link is just about how to share files in general, and does not describe how the "courtesy copy" differs from the e-mail collaborators received.  What are all those differences?  Why are those differences there?